# Select multiple entries on the same date by same user MySQL

Tags: mysql

i'm looking to output a list of users that have double booked on the same date from my mysql database.

and example of The booking table is below and the firstname and lastname woulde be joined on bookings.memberid = members.memberid:

```
bookingid  |  memberid  |  time  | date  | group
---------------------------------------------------
1          |    1       | 7:00   | 24/04 | 1
34         |   1        | 14:00  | 24/04 | 4
```

Sorry for the brevity, i'm currently on the way to a christening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try self joining your booking table like:

```
SELECT *
FROM BOOKING b1 INNER JOIN Booking b2
ON b1.memberid = b2.memberid
AND b1.date = b2.date
WHERE b1.bookingid != b2.bookingid
```

Comment: Thank you, I would then add another join to the members table to get the first and last name I presume?

Comment: Yes if your booking table doesnt have name of user, then yes you would have to.